# Activate tmux within a emacs shell

Tags: emacs

Invoking 'shell' by `M-x shell`,
and plan to start a tmux session

it report errors

```
$ tmux 
open terminal failed: terminal does not support clear
```

What's the problem?

If invoking `ansi-term', the operations of yanking and pasting are invalid.

So, `shell` perform better than ansi-term in routines.

How could activate tmux within a shell

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tmux` needs a real terminal, and `shell` doesn't provide that (as implied by the error you get).  So you need to use `term` with `tmux`.

Or you can use built in functionality of Emacs to have features of `tmux`.  E.g. `C-x 2` and `C-x 3` will split the frame into windows so you can have multiple terminals in a frame (an Emacs frame is what most applications would call a window).  Start an emacs server and `emacsclient` to have sessions that you can connect to and keep running after you close the frame.

Copy (`M-w`) and paste (`S-<insert>`) should work by default.  If you want to play with bindings, the key map is called `term-raw-map` and the commands are `kill-ring-save` and `term-paste`.

Also learn the difference between `term-line-mode` (`C-c C-j`) and `term-char-mode` (`C-c C-k`).  Briefly, line mode behaves more like `shell`, and char mode behaves more like a real terminal, with most Emacs keybindings unavailable.  I personally keep `term` buffers in char mode almost always and add some keybindings to `term-raw-map` so I can run certain Emacs commands.